# How to list out packages installed from source in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, package, installation

I have installed a package and wants to verify if it is installed or not.

Steps Followed:

wget url;
tar -xf file name
cd folder name
./configure
[installed necessary package]
make
sudo make install

After doing this, some files are created at /usr/local/library of same name as package but packagename --version is returning command not found

Comment: did you source your bashrc?

Comment: Did it, Still command not found

Comment: it would be easier if you said what package you are trying to install from source.

Comment: libcroco0-0.6.8 and gdk-pixbuf-2.0